# How to make a dynamic list using queue approach

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am working on vue.js rendering dynamic list, When user clicks on a button then the link in corresponding input field renders,  then again I am pasting a link in input field and clicking add it adds the value to the second index which I don't want I know I have o use `queue` concept but here on ui I don't how to implement it

**What I have done**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {

      anchorTags: [{
        url: '',
        value: ''
      }]

    }

  },
  methods: {

    validateYouTubeUrl() {

      var url = document.getElementById('youtubeUrl').value

      this.anchorTags.push({
        url: url,
        value: url
      });

    }

  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id=app>
  <div class="container-fluid row">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8" id="first">

      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="youtubeUrl" placeholder="Paste link here...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="validateYouTubeUrl">Add</button>

        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" id="second">
      <h3 class="form-control">Playlist</h3>
      <hr>


      <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="(anchorTag, k) in anchorTags" :key="k" class="list-group-item">
          <a :href="anchorTag.url" @click.prevent="playVideo($event)">{{anchorTag.value}}</a>
          <span v-if="anchorTag.url!==''"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So What I am trying to do is**

To do it like quee like FIFO, when I enter some thing it is on top the again I enter something the latest one should be on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allowed myself to make some extra changes, moreover, to give you an answer (I used the `v-model`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      youtubeUrl: null,
      anchorTags: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validateYouTubeUrl() {
      this.anchorTags.push({
        url: this.youtubeUrl,
        value: this.youtubeUrl
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    anchorList() {
      return this.anchorTags.slice().reverse();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 3em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id=app>
  <div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8" id="first">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="youtubeUrl" placeholder="Paste link here...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="validateYouTubeUrl">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" id="second">
      <h3 class="form-control">Playlist</h3>
      <hr>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="(anchorTag, k) in anchorList" :key="k" class="list-group-item">
          <a :href="anchorTag.url" @click.prevent="playVideo($event)">{{anchorTag.value}}</a>
          <span v-if="anchorTag.url!==''"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that's not what you meant, edit your question and try to describe it in a more pathological way.